# Issue generating RSA encrypted text in java, can't decrypt in .net

Tags: java, .net, encryption, rsa

I've been given the task to generate a ticket in Java (OpenJDK 11) to login to an external website. Currently this ticket is being generated by .net code (2.0), from which I don't have the source, so we had to decompile the DLLs and work from there.

I have received a modulus and a public exponent (both base64 encoded) from the provider.

```
MODULUS = "yBl8llKaMhEeMxI/fyUN07l5GwhQDlhAnNzoui....=";
EXPONENT = "AQAB";
```

The ticket to generate consists of 3 parts:
(1) data: AES encrypted "username"
(2) key: RSA encrypted AES key
(3) IV: RSA encrypted IV

The target website will decrypt the key and IV and use these to decrypt the "data". From the decompiled DLLs, I can see that RSACryptoServiceProvider is being used for RSA, and RijndaelManaged for AES.

I generate the public key:

```
BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, Base64.decodeBase64(MODULUS.getBytes(UTF_8)));
BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, Base64.decodeBase64(EXPONENT.getBytes(UTF_8)));

RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKey = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
publicKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPubKey);
```

The AES keysize used is 128 bits:

```
 KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
 keyGenerator.init(128);
 MyKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
```

The AES encryption method:

```
AESCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(MyKey.getEncoded(), "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(AESCipher.getIV())
```

And the RSA encryption method:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data);
```

The problem is that I cannot see why the login is failing, we just get a "login failed" message but don't see any details.

I know from the decompiled code that no OAEP is being used on the .net side:

```
this.rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
Convert.ToBase64String(this.rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strData), false));
```

I've tried different key sizes, padding modes,... but I'm all out of ideas now. Am I missing something obvious? I realize we are working blindfolded here, without any more information to operate on.

"Full example" code below:

```
    String AES_TRANSFORMATION = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    String RSA_TRANSFORMATION = "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding";
    String ALGORITHM = "AES";

    String MODULUS = "yBl8llKaMhEeMxI/fyUN07l5GwhQDlhAnNzoui...=";
    String EXPONENT = "AQAB";
    String USER_NAME = "myusernamehere";

    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
    keyGenerator.init(keysize);
    String AES_KEY = keyGenerator.generateKey();

    Cipher AESCipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_TRANSFORMATION);

    private void test() {
        BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, Base64.decodeBase64(MODULUS.getBytes(UTF_8)));
        BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, Base64.decodeBase64(EXPONENT.getBytes(UTF_8)));

        RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKey = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
        KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        publicKey = fact.generatePublic(rsaPubKey);

        String data = aes_encrypt((USER_NAME).getBytes());
        String key = rsa_encrypt(AES_KEY.getEncoded(), publicKey);
        String iv = rsa_encrypt(AESCipher.getIV(), publicKey);
    }

    private String aes_encrypt(byte[] data) {
        byte[] encryptedData = new byte[0];
        AESCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(AES_KEY.getEncoded(), "AES"));
        encryptedData = AESCipher.doFinal(data);
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedData);
    }

    private String rsa_encrypt(byte[] data, PublicKey publicKey) {
        byte[] cipherData = new byte[0];
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA_TRANSFORMATION);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        cipherData = cipher.doFinal(data);
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(cipherData);
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] please?

Comment: We cannot tell why the server is replying this way because we (and maybe you) don't have a protocol specification. Without that, any kind of *encoding mistake* may already let the server barf out an error. By the way, yesterday I was writing [a blog post about wrapper classes](https://owlstead.github.io/on_wrapper_libraries.html) like `AESCipher ` that you may be interested in. It's only semi public, so you would possibly the second person to read it. Good, off you go and get that protocol specification!

Comment: By the way, `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strData)` doesn't indicate any usage of AES, an AES key does *not* consists of text.

Comment: interesting article! I added the complete code for clarification as I didn't use the AESCipher wrapper class, I just accidentally named the cipher that way). The data, iv and key are passed as simple form parameters, and submitted during an post so I'm not sure what protocol spec you are referring to?

Comment: Well, for instance do you need base64 encoding or base64url encoding? You need to know the *exact* calculation, format and representation of these fields. In short I'm referring to the protocol spec that the other party has forsaken to write and is now fucking you over with, because it takes your time instead of theirs. It doesn't need to be much, but *it does need to be there*. Ugh, please keep to Java coding conventions and use `aesCipher`; I'm too easily wrong footed nowadays.